# Problem with proving formally tautology using given rules

Tags: logic, proof-verification, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

> Using the rules below prove that the following assumeptions leads to the following conclusion by tautology.
>
> $A\vee B \vee C,  A\to C, B\to C \Rightarrow C$
>
> [image]

What I did:

1. $A\vee B \vee C$ Assumption
2. $A\to C$  Assumption
3. $B\to C$  Assumption
4. $A\vee B\to C$ rule 11 on lines 2,3
5. $\neg\neg(A\lor B \lor C)$ rule 7 on line 1
6. $\neg (\neg A\land \neg B \land \neg C)$ rule 14 on line 5
7. $\neg\neg A$ rule 3 on line 6
8. $A$ rule 7 on line 7
9. $A\vee B$ rule 5 on line 8
10. $C$ rule 1 on line 4, 9 $\square$

But there seems to be a problem since I get that $(A\vee B \vee C)\to A$ which can't be right... So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There is an error in line 6, each $\lor$ should be a $\land$.

Comment: @James Typo. Fixed.

Comment: Well, now in step 7, your application of rule 3 is incorrect. You 6 is not a conjunction, it is the negation of a conjunction.

Comment: @James aha, but why is it not correct to apply it to the conjunction inside the negation?

Comment: Well, basically, because $\neg(\neg A \land \neg B \land \neg C)$ is equivalent to $A \lor B \lor C$ which does not imply $A$! More technically, the $\Rightarrow$ substitutions preserve truth: If you have a true anticedent, you have a true consequent. They, however, do not preserve falsity (for that you need $\Leftrightarrow$) i.e. you can have a false antecedent but a true consequent.

Comment: @James well thank you, you could make that an answer if you want to and I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: @kuhaku It's good that you want to accept *an* answer.  But, James hasn't actually solved this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Polish/Lukasiewicz notation.

Rule 1 says

```
a, Cab -> b.
```

Rule 11 (R11) says

```
Cac, Cbc -> C Aab c
```

Thus, we'll derive a rule first, which I'll denote R16.  The rule is Cac, Cbc, Aab -> c.

```
assumption 1 Cac
assumption 2 Cbc
assumption 3 Aab
1, 2, R11  4 CAabc
3, 4, R1   5 c
```

Now we'll solve the problem:

```
assumption     1 AAabc
assumption     2 Cac
assumption     3 Cbc
2, 3 R11       4 C Aab c
T13, 1, 4, R16 5 c
```

where T13 is Caa or any substitution instance of it such as Ccc.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this notation, I'm gonna have to decipher what's going on in here.